# Call async method and use its response inside useRef in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to call Async function and use its response inside of useRef in react like the below:

```
const myComponent = () => {
    const getTitle = async () => { 
        const res = await fetch('title');
        return res;
    }

    const myref = useRef(
         Employee().retire({
             id: 1,
             title: await getTitle(),
         }),
    );
}
```

However, I cannot use await inside of useRef. What other way to accomplish this?

Comment: You're not returning anything from `getTitle`.

Comment: Is `myRef` inside an async function because you can't use `await` without it being inside an async function. You'll probably need to first initialise the `useRef` and then use an async function inside a `useEffect` to update it.

Comment: useref is inside the main component, and the react component cannot be async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the ref

```
const myRef = useRef(null);
```

And then use `useEffect` to update it once when the component renders:

```
// `getTitle` doesn't need to be async because
// you're apparently already returning a promise
function getTitle() { 
  return fetch('title');
}

useEffect(() => {

  // Call an async function in your `useEffect`
  // to wait for the promise to resolve and use the data
  // to update the ref
  async function getData() {
    const title = await getTitle();
    myRef.current = Employee().retire({ id: 1, title });
  }
  getData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Ts is complaining about getTitle not added to the dependencies array, should I add it? Or is there a way to avoid adding it at all?

Comment: Perhaps use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know is set `myref` **after** async function is solved. Something like:

```
const myComponent = () => {
    const getTitle = async () => { 
        const res = await fetch('title');
        return res;
    }

    const myref = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
       (async () => {
          let title = await getTitle();
          myref.current = Employee().retire({ id: 1, title });
          console.log(myref.current);
       })();
    }, []);
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useref-forked-20lrh?file=/src/index.js:358-462) a working example.

Comment: Ts is complaining about getTitle not added to the dependencies array, should I add it? Or is there a way to avoid adding it at all?

Answer (score 0):

`await` keyword using only inside of `async` function

Comment: useref is inside the main component, and the react component cannot be async

Comment: Try to change your logics. Create the ref after fetch is done by chained `then`

Comment: that is what i typically need, but how to accomplish that (check my updated question)